# compatability issues between QtDesigner5.11.0, python3.5, and pyside2?

Tags: python-3.x, qt-designer, pyside2, qstackedwidget

I've had good success with QtDesigner5.11 and python3.5 in creating QtWindows. Now I want to use QtDesigner to create linked Qt objects(frames) in a StackedWidget.

I read that PySide is obsolete and that I should use PySide2.  From what I read, Pyside2 is suitable for Python3.6.

Can I use Pyside2 with my present configuration of QtDesigner5.11 and Python3.5, or should I let Conda install a bunch of upgrades with c:\myUser\conda install pyside2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PySide2 is Python 3.5 compatible according to the [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted).
I don't know if conda has the technical preview of PySide2, but I recomend you to use pip following the intructions of the [official blog post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/06/13/qt-python-5-11-released/)